# Another way,list view click event using setOnClikListener Not an ItemclickListener

Tags: android

i would like to implement, while i select list view that time my check box will be selected. 
[image]

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mycheckbox);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    MyList mylist = mItems.get(position);

holder.text.setText(mylist.getMyText());


    holder.checkbox.setChecked(mChecked.get(position));
holder.chkItem.setChecked(mChecked.get(position));
    holder.chkItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
     {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mChecked.set((Integer) buttonView.getTag(),isChecked);

        }
     });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox checkbox;
    TextView text;
}
}
```

here the check box item only selected, but i want if i click list view, check box will be selected, any one cane help me? why i am asking the same question again mean i tried list  view click event through item click listener, but its not working i tried setFocusable(true) also, but not working.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/172496)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my answer,

```
convertView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Below is hardcoded to get item at index 1
            // This needs to be changed to fool-proof
            CheckBox checkBox = ((CheckBox)v.getTouchables().get(1));
            checkBox.setChecked(! checkBox.isChecked()); 

            System.out.println("Listview clicked");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use onitemclicklistener on list object.if row will be selected,checkbox will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement onItemClickListener to your list.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
              ViewHolder yourView = (ViewHolder) view;
              //do whatever you want with your view..
            }
    });
```

Comment: first i tried this type but its not working for me, so i tried another type now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Mark the checkbox as focusable="false" in the XML layout for your list item. Then handle the listview's onClickListener, and toggle the checked state of the checkbox.

Without focusable="false" the checkbox will steal clicks from the listview.